# SSH access and control

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, sudo

IS there an ideal way to limit access to server admins as to what they can and can not do with sudo? I would like to have levels of access from basic command line actions to more advanced abilities such as service control. I also do not want them having the ability to touch root or edit logs.

I'm running CentOS 6 with CPanel on the boxes.

Comment: What do this have to do with SSH access and control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use command aliases to permit, or forbid such actions, for instance:

```
Cmnd_Alias OPS  = /usr/sbin/shutdown,\
                  /usr/sbin/reboot,\
                  /bin/su,\
                  /bin/sh,\
                  /bin/csh


%dev        ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL, !OPS
```

Basically, `%dev` means anyone part of the dev group, can do anything, as any user, EXCEPT `OPS` which provides a list of commands you do not wish them to run as sudo.

Alternatively you can create your own Cmnd_Alias and do `%dev  ALL=OPS` to permit the use of only the listed operations.

Comment: I personally think this is the best answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can define separate allowed sudo commands per user. For instance instead of giving them all commands we can give a certain user called testing the permission to restart the webserver with sudo:

```
testing ALL=/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

(this should be in your sudoers file)

Answer (score 1):

Besides `sudo`, you can write scripts to do things with suid bit set (not necessarily suid root, maybe suid www-data or even suid nobody) and group execute bit set, and allow people to run it by adding them to the appropriate group that owns the script in question.

`sudo` is better, because it leaves a verbose audit trail and can be quite flexible, though the `sudoers(5)` man page is rather human-unfriendly and full of Backus-Naur spaghetti. And `sudo` tends to throw up and stop working on any syntax error in /etc/sudoers, so you'd better set yourself a real root password for the time you set up `sudoers` file, or you may find yourself locked out with broken `sudo`.

`sudo` or not `sudo`, be very careful when designing scripts, parsing command line arguments, writing to admin-controllable files.

One example, let's imagine you have a script that gets invoked under a privileged account (root or whatever), and by the way it writes with truncation (>) to a file that your admin can replace with a symlink pointing somewhere you never thought of.

Another example, editing /etc/network/interfaces (or an analog of it in your distro) and then ifup'ing an interface may seem innocent, but there are pre/post-up/down scripts that are invoked as root. Oops.